# How to let maven resolve transitive dependency for local dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

We have a project A which depends on project B which depends on library C. A and B are local projects while C is a public library in maven central repo.

pom.xml for A:

```
<name>ProjA/name>
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ProjB</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

pom.xml for B:

```
<name>ProjB/name>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>C</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.2</version>
</dependency>
```

When run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` in A, it does not resolve the dependencies of B and such dependencies used in B is not shown in A's Maven Dependencies as well. This is fine for compilation but will fail in runtime because of NoClassDefFound error.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ProjA 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ ProjA ---
[INFO] com.abc.projA:jar:1.0
[INFO] +- com.abc.projB:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.326 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-15T16:29:49-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there any way to let maven resolve transitive dependency for such local dependency as B?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is B does not exist in the local repo `.m2`

You need to run `mvn install` for B, to install the package into  `.m2` which can be picked up by A locally.

Then running `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` in A won't cause problem

Comment: The weird thing is B is installed to .m2 already for the purpose of building A. The B.jar is in the correct location .m2/com/abc/ProjB/1.0 and inside the B.jar/META-INF/maven/com.abc/ProjB/pom.xml all dependencies including C are there as well.